# Swift code generation to Realm classes

Tags: ios, swift, realm, objectmapper

Does anyone know a tool that could convert plain Swift class to a Realm class that inherits from `Object`? Ideally it could also conform to `Mappable` from ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generator but you can use this https://github.com/tsrnd/realm-mapper-ios

Comment: How is this different from using Realm and ObjectMapper separately like described here: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#objectmapper--realm ?

Comment: It has additional methods and operators which speed up your work